# Cross Validation with ROC?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation, roc, model-validation

I use the code to run cross validation, returning ROC scores.

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1000,oob_score=True,class_weight  = 'balanced') 
scores = cross_val_score ( rf, X,np.ravel(y), cv=10, scoring='roc_auc')
```

How can I return the ROC based on

```
roc_auc_score(y_test,results.predict(X_test))
```

rather than

```
roc_auc_score(y_test,results.predict_proba(X_test))
```

Comment: ROC AUC is only useful if you can rank order your predictions. Using `.predict()` will just give the most probable class for each sample, and so you won't be able to do that rank ordering.

Answer (score 1):

ROC AUC is only useful if you can rank order your predictions. Using `.predict()` will just give the most probable class for each sample, and so you won't be able to do that rank ordering.

In the example below, I fit a random forest on a randomly generated dataset and tested it on a held out sample. The blue line shows the proper ROC curve done using `.predict_proba()` while the green shows the degenerate one with `.predict()` where it only really knows of the one cutoff point.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

rf = RandomForestClassifier()

data, target = make_classification(n_samples=4000, n_features=2, n_redundant=0, flip_y=0.4)
train, test, train_t, test_t = train_test_split(data, target, train_size=0.9)

rf.fit(train, train_t)

plt.plot(*roc_curve(test_t, rf.predict_proba(test)[:,1])[:2])
plt.plot(*roc_curve(test_t, rf.predict(test))[:2])
plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT:** While there's nothing stopping you from calculating an `roc_auc_score()` on `.predict()`, the point of the above is that it's not really a useful measurement.

```
In [5]: roc_auc_score(test_t, rf.predict_proba(test)[:,1]), roc_auc_score(test_t, rf.predict(test))
Out[5]: (0.75502749115010925, 0.70238005573548234)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I concern the ROC score rather than ROC curve. So I wanna get roc_auc_score(y_test,results.predict(X_test))

Comment: @LUSAQX there is no such thing as ROC score, do you mean AUC (area under the curve?)

Comment: I mean roc_auc_score().

Comment: `roc_auc_score()` is just the area underneath an ROC curve. You can easily calculate the area under that green curve with `roc_auc_score()`, but the point of my answer is that it's going to be essentially a meaningless number since all you really have is a single sensitivity/specificity measurement by using `.predict()`

Comment: What does the `*` do in `roc_curve()`?

Comment: @Chris `roc_curve` returns 3 elements, and I want to pass the first two to `plt.plot`. The `[:2]` picks off the first two elements, and the `*` is the argument unpacking operator to pass those as two separate inputs to `plt.plot` (see e.g., https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/ for more detail on how that works).